# How to efficiently remove event listeners by namespace from ALL DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know I can do it like this: `$('*').off('.namespace');`

But I have the feeling that `*` is not a good idea, because jQuery will go through the whole DOM tree and that will be slow.

jQuerys internal `$.cache` contains information about event listeners that were bound via `.on()`

Is there any way to tell jQuery to just go through that internal cache and remove all event listeners from a specific namespace from any elements - without having to `*` the DOM tree?

**Edit:** The problem is I don't know to which elements the listeners were bound - I only know the namespace they were bound to.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put a hook on each element as and when you bind an event to it?

```
$('.some_el').addClass('has_foo_event').on('click.foo', function() {});
```

Then

```
$('.has_foo_event').off('.foo');
```

Comment: That's want I want to do, but the problem is I don't know to which elements the listeners were bound. I only know the namespace they use.